# Currency field constraint check done before rounding off

Tags: xforms, orbeon

HI All
i was unit testing my currency field and i found this issue that can be considered as a bug.

```
<xforms:bind id="amount" nodeset="instance('form')/data/amount"
constraint="if(.!='') then number(.) >0 and string-length(.)&lt;20 else ."/>
...
<fr:currency bind="amount" xxforms:maxlength="50" incremental="true">
   <xforms:alert>Value should be below $ 9,999,999,999,999,999,999.99</xforms:alert>
</fr:currency>
```

The condition that i am trying to achieve in the above case is, to put a max value check < "9999999,999999999.99" this has 19 characters total. (i had tried constraint="if(.='') then true() else number(.)<10000000000000000"  also instead of length check, but later seeing some bug in that number check switched to this string-length check)

now the issue in this case of string length is 
if i enter "9,999,999,999,999,999.991" the following happens
1. the constraint check is performed. which returns 'false' as "9999999999999999.991" = 20 length
2. the currency amount is rounded off.

so my constraint check fails. But if i click the field and click outside the field, the constraint check returns true

can anyone suggest a better way to do it or how to solve the above issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to note:

`xxforms:maxlength` does not work on `fr:currency` or any other `fr:` control

Numbers are evaluated against other numbers as a [double-precision 64-bit floating point type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-2-20010502/#double).  Take this into account when numbers are being evaluated.  Basically what this means is large numbers get rounded.  it is possible that problems you experience with large number evaluations is not a bug but rather just math.

- For example, the numbers between 9999999999999998976.00  and 10000000000000001023.99 all evaluate to 1.0E19

Comment: we have found a complex way to do the validation by using constraint="matches(., '(^$)|(^(\d){0,16}(\.\d\d?)?$)')" this seems to validate properly